NMaximize doesn't satisfy constraints
I have the following code;
m = 30 10^2;
s = 10;
t = -Log[2, 10^-(s + 2)];

delta = 455 10^-4;
epsqkd = 10^-(s);

binent[p_] := -p Log[2, p] - (1 - p) Log[2, (1 - p)];

r = 119 10^-2  binent[delta];

epspa[nu_, beta_, alpha_] := 
  1/2 Sqrt[
    2^(-(m - beta m) (1 - binent[delta + nu]) + r (m - beta m) + t + 
       alpha m)];

gammaFunc[n_, k_, merr_, m_] := 1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1);

epspe[nu_, eta_, beta_] := 
  Sqrt[Exp[-2 m beta m eta^2/(m - beta m + 1)] + 
    Exp[-2 gammaFunc[m - beta m, beta m, m (delta + eta), 
       m] ((m - beta m)^2 (nu - eta)^2 - 1)]];

vars = {alpha, beta, nu, eta}; 

cons = {alpha m, (epsqkd - (2^-t + 2 epspe[nu, eta, beta] + 
       epspa[nu, beta, alpha ])) == 0, 10^-5 <= alpha <= 10^-1, 
  3 10^-1 < beta <= 1/2, 0 < nu < 1/2 - delta, 0 < eta < nu};

res = NMaximize[cons, vars, Method -> "RandomSearch", WorkingPrecision -> 64, MaxIterations -> 100]

I cant get the program to satisfy all the constraints. Either one or both of the following constraints fails;
(*constraint 1*)

(epsqkd - (2^-t + 2 epspe[nu, eta, beta] + 
       epspa[nu, beta, alpha ])) == 0 

(*constraint 2*)

0 < eta < nu

I have tried enforcing constraint 1 by multiplying the constraint with a large value, say $10^{10}$. In my caseepsqkd have extremely low values; around $10^{-6} - 10^{-10}$. But if the constraint 1 is satisfied constraint 2 fails.
How can I get NMaximize to follow all the constarints? How could I modify constraint 2?

It appears that the feasible set is empty.
Indeed,
m = 30  10^2;s = 10;t = -Log[2, 10^-(s + 2)];delta = 455  10^-4;
epsqkd = 10^-(s);binent[p_] := -p  Log[2, p] - (1 - p)  Log[2, (1 - p)];
r = 119  10^-2   binent[delta];
epspa[nu_, beta_, alpha_] := 
 1/2  Sqrt[
2^(-(m - beta  m)  (1 - binent[delta + nu]) + r  (m - beta  m) + 
   t + alpha  m)];
gammaFunc[n_, k_, merr_, m_] := 1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1);
epspe[nu_, eta_, beta_] := 
Sqrt[Exp[-2  m  beta  m  eta^2/(m - beta  m + 1)] + 
Exp[-2  gammaFunc[m - beta  m, beta  m, m  (delta + eta),    m]*
((m - beta  m)^2  (nu - eta)^2 - 1)]];
vars = {alpha, beta, nu, eta};
NMaximize[{epsqkd-(2^-t+2 epspe[nu,eta,beta]+epspa[nu,beta,alpha]),
10^-5<=alpha<=10^-1&&3 10^-1<beta<=1/2&&0<nu<1/2-delta&&0<eta<nu},vars,
WorkingPrecision->20]


{-0.000081182641556415618068, {alpha -> 0.000010000000000000000000,  beta -> 0.31629013471512422490, nu -> 0.12003314154983810468,  eta -> 0.085835852708882336123}}

Therefore, the restriction epsqkd-(2^-t+2   epspe[nu,eta,beta]+epspa[nu,beta,alpha])==0 cannot be satisfied.
